# error fetching a cursor

Tags: mysql, cursor

I am working on this cursor that fetch the salary column of a table and see if a value is bigger than 2500 we should take 500 as tax, and ELSE we should take only 200, and finally select and show the table with a new column with salary after taxes:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tax_to_salary`()
BEGIN
DECLARE basic_salary INTEGER;
DECLARE new_salary INTEGER;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT salary FROM employee;
OPEN cur1;
l1:LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO basic_salary;
IF basic_salary>2500 THEN
SET @new_salary := 500;
SET @basic_salary := @basic_salary - @new_salary;
else
SET @new_salary := 200;
SET @basic_salary := @basic_salary - @new_salary;
END IF;
END LOOP;
SELECT emp_name, salary, basic_salary AS 'Salary after taxes' FROM employee; 
END
```

I have got this error:

> zero rows fetched selected or processed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about exit handlers and Continue handlers
 [MySQL handlers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-handler.html)

Try something like below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tax_to_salary`()
BEGIN
DECLARE basic_salary INTEGER;
DECLARE new_salary INTEGER;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT salary FROM employee;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN cur1;
l1:LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO basic_salary;
IF basic_salary>2500 THEN
SET @new_salary := 500;
SET @basic_salary := @basic_salary - @new_salary;
else
SET @new_salary := 200;
SET @basic_salary := @basic_salary - @new_salary;
END IF;
END LOOP;
SELECT emp_name, salary, basic_salary AS 'Salary after taxes' FROM employee; 
END
```

Comment: What does exactly this line do to this procedure ?

Comment: `CURSOR` are loops, Handlers are used when loop ends.

Comment: your code taked me into unfinished LOOP and Workbench stopped working

Comment: hahaha, it might be due to something else, try relaunching workbench and run it again, it will work definitely.

Comment: Actually, there's a critical line missing, here.  Immediately after the `FETCH` statement, you need `IF done THEN LEAVE l1; END IF;`. Otherwise, you have an endless loop.